# Error when try to update text in French/English to mysql db

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I have one page to edit data. In this case, I will show the page to edit French data. The problem is that, when I paste the text in French and click to edit and update, it assumes mysql_error. This just happens with French and English, I can do it right in Portuguese. I'm using only this tree languages.

I've tried some ways, but nothing happened...
What is commented is that what I tried.

When I press the button, that is what happens : "Ocorreu um erro, tente de novo! You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ont forcé à travailler comme apprenti à l'usine d'orfèvrerie de son ' at line 1"

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $cookie_name = "loggedin";
    if (isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])){
        $cookie_value = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
    }else {
        echo "O seu tempo expirou, inicie sessão novamente!";
        header("Refresh:2; url=/estagio/admin/login.php");
    }

    ini_set ('default_charset', 'UTF-8');


    mysql_set_charset('utf8');

    //header ("content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

    //mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    //mysql_query("SET character_set_connection=utf8");
    //mysql_query("SET character_set_client=utf8");
    //mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8");

    mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Erro na conexão " .mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db ("casadoadro") or die ("Erro na seleção da base de dados " .mysql_error());


    $editid = $_GET['eid'];

    if (!isset($_GET['eid']) || empty($_GET['eid'])){
        header ("location: admin_biografia.php");
    }

    $editquery = mysql_query("select * from tb_biografia where id='{$editid}'") or die (mysql_error());
    $editdata = mysql_fetch_row($editquery);


    if ($_POST)
    {
        $id = htmlspecialchars ($_POST['id']);
        $title_fr = htmlspecialchars ($_POST['title_fr']);
        $subtitle_fr = htmlspecialchars ($_POST['subtitle_fr']);
        $text_fr = htmlspecialchars ($_POST['text_fr']);

        $q = mysql_query ("UPDATE tb_biografia SET title_fr='{$title_fr}', subtitle_fr='{$subtitle_fr}', text_fr='{$text_fr}'  WHERE id='{$id}'") or die ("Ocorreu um erro, tente de novo! " .mysql_error());

        if($q){
            echo "<script>alert ('Editado com sucesso'); window.location='admin_biografia.php'</script>";
        }
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/estagio/css/styles.css">
        <title>Casa do adro</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="col-2"></div>
        <div class="col-8"> 
                <div class="col-12 w3-card-4 nopadding">
                    <form method="post" class="w3-container w3margin" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="hidden" name="size" value="10000000" />
                        <div class="w3-row mtb">
                            <div class="w3-col" style="width:150px">ID</div>
                            <div class="w3-rest">
                                <?php echo $editdata[0]; ?>
                                <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="hidden" name="id"  value="<?php echo $editdata[0]; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="w3-row mtb">
                            <div class="w3-col" style="width:150px">Título FR</div>
                            <div class="w3-rest">
                                <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" name="title_fr"  value="<?php echo $editdata[2]; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="w3-row mtb">
                            <div class="w3-col" style="width:150px">Legenda FR</div>
                            <div class="w3-rest">
                                <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" name="subtitle_fr"  value="<?php echo $editdata[6]; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="w3-row mtb">
                            <div class="w3-col" style="width:150px">Texto FR</div>
                            <div class="w3-rest">
                                <div class="w3-rest">
                                <textarea class="w3-input w3-border" rows="1" type="text" name="text_fr"><?php echo $editdata[9]; ?></textarea>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <button class="btnfbform w3-block mtb w3-ripple  w3-input w3-border" type="submit" name="upload"> Editar texto</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2"></div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: just change this `title_fr='{$title_fr}'` with `title_fr='".$title_fr."'` it will work.

Comment: you are welcome and now you can check my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with this. Hope it helps. Thanks. Use mysql_real_escape_string to escape special characters and remove {} in your query for php variable.

```
if ($_POST)
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $title_fr = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title_fr']);
    $subtitle_fr = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subtitle_fr']);
    $text_fr = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text_fr']);

    $q = mysql_query ("UPDATE tb_biografia SET title_fr='$title_fr', subtitle_fr='$subtitle_fr', text_fr='$text_fr'  WHERE id='$id}'") or die ("Ocorreu um erro, tente de novo! " .mysql_error());

    if($q){
        echo "<script>alert ('Editado com sucesso'); window.location='admin_biografia.php'</script>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR use `htmlspecialchars($_POST['text_fr]', ENT_QUOTES)` or use some SQL library

The text in $title_fr, $text_fr or other siilar variable probably contains a single quote character (') that messes up your query.

Let's say the value of `$_POST['text_fr']` is `C'est la vie`.

Then the resulting query will look somewhat like this:

```
UPDATE tb_biografia SET text_fr='C'est la vie'  WHERE id='10'
```

As you see, the quote that should delimit the string and the quote in the string itself mixes together and the resulting query is completely invalid. Even the syntax highliter here on Stack overflow is confused by that.

This is a huge security flaw that enables SQL injection attacks. Never compose SQL queries from user input by yourself if you are not perfectly sure that you know what you are doing.

The problem in your case is behavior of function `htmlspecialchars`. It DOES NOT escape single quotes by default, only double quotes. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php. You need to supply second argument, ENT_QUOTES, so that it will encode also single quotes.

```
$text_fr = htmlspecialchars ($_POST['text_fr'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

Viva la PHP!

However, I really recommend you to use some tool that helps with building the query and protects you from similar mistakes:

- PDO and prepared statements (part of PHP core)
- NotORM, Dibi, SQL query builder... lightweight libraries for easier manipulation with SQL databases
- Doctrine or similar ORM framework - for heavy lifting on bigger projects.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the value like `'{$title_fr}'` which will produce an error
just change this

```
title_fr='{$title_fr}'
```

with

```
title_fr='".$title_fr."'
```

it will work.